# String array to Array List issue in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm facing some issue in java collection util, basically I am using **removeall()** on arrayList by breaking the steps but it throwing **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException** and when I am doing it in single line it working finely as expected. So I don't understand what's the problem when I breaking it in several steps. The code is

```
public class Test4 {

public static void main(String args[]){
    String unInstall="com.mobikwik_new,com.cleanmaster.mguard,com.htc.flashlight,com.mobilemotion.dubsmash";
    String  install="com.mobikwik_new,com.cleanmaster.mguard,com.htc.flashlight";
    List<String> installList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> unInstallList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String inL[] = install.split(",");
    String UnInL[] = unInstall.split(",");
    installList = Arrays.asList(inL);
    unInstallList = Arrays.asList(UnInL);
    unInstallList.remove(installList);
    //List<String> installList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(install.split(",")));
    //List<String> unInstallList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(unInstall.split(",")));

    unInstallList.removeAll(installList);

    System.out.println("unInstall : "+unInstallList);
}
}
```

**Note:** when I am using only the commented line instead of all above steps its working fine

The exception it throwing is -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source)
at Test4.main(Test4.java:21)
```

Thanks !

Comment: which one is line  21?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a list that is fixed-size, because it's backed by the array that's given as argument. The returned list doesn't support the `remove` operation, as is indicated by the error message you're seeing.

If you want to remove something from the list, wrap the returned list in an `ArrayList`: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(inL));`.

Comment: Thanks Buddy !! got it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source off ArrayList the method remove is not supported:

```
 616:   /**
 617:    * Remove the element at a given position in this list (optional operation).
 618:    * Shifts all remaining elements to the left to fill the gap. This
 619:    * implementation always throws an UnsupportedOperationException.
 620:    * If you want fail-fast iterators, be sure to increment modCount when
 621:    * overriding this.
 622:    *
 623:    * @param index the position within the list of the object to remove
 624:    * @return the object that was removed
 625:    * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if this list does not support the
 626:    *         remove operation
 627:    * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index &lt; 0 || index &gt;= size()
 628:    * @see #modCount
 629:    */
 630:   public E remove(int index)
 631:   {
 632:     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
 633:   }
 634:
```

So you can not remove an ellement using this method.

Comment: I think that this answer might be more useful if you described how to find this out (e.g. Arrays.asList returns a java.util.Arrays.ArrayList, which extends AbstractCollection and doesn't override its remove method).

Comment: Strange, I checked the ArrayList implementation and the remove and removeAll methods were supported.

Comment: @Michal did you check `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`? The latter is the relevant one.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing, which confused me. There are two different ArrayList classes :)

Comment: Thanks Andy, now I understand the issue.